# Auto deselect onclick checkbox using JS

Tags: javascript, salesforce-marketing-cloud

First thing's first. I can't use JQuery, only JS.

I have some checkboxes all with different names. I need the different names. I then have another checkbox that when clicked should deselect the previous checkboxes.

```js
var isAllCheck = false;

function togglecheckboxes(cn) {

  var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
  for (var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++) {

    cbarray[i].checked = !isAllCheck
  }
  isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="email">
<input type="checkbox" name="phone">
<input type="checkbox" name="sms">
<input type="checkbox" name="whatsapp">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglecheckboxes('cb')" value="Toggle all">
```

if the names are all 'cb' then it works but I need them to be different. Is there anyway i can get this to work while maintaining different names?

huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the checkboxes, or only deselect previous checkbox (so only last one remains checked)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByClassName()` instead of `getElementsByName()`. This way they can all have individual names, but a common class that you use to collect them all and deselect their checkboxes. Remember that HTML-elements can also have multiple classes, so this works even if you need to do some specific styling on the different checkboxes using classes, while elements can only have a single name. For this reason you generally always want to do logical operations on multiple elements using a common class (or an ID if you're targetting only one specific element).

```js
var isAllCheck = false;
  function togglecheckboxes(cn){

      var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(cn);
      for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

          cbarray[i].checked = !isAllCheck
  }   
  isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
```

```html
<input class="cn" type="checkbox" name="email">
<input class="cn" type="checkbox" name="phone">
<input class="cn" type="checkbox" name="sms">
<input class="cn" type="checkbox" name="whatsapp">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglecheckboxes('cn')" value="Toggle all">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select elements based on their attributes like class name.

```js
var isAllCheck = false;

function togglecheckboxes() {

  var cbarray = document.querySelectorAll('input.check-box');
  for (var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++) {
    cbarray[i].checked = !isAllCheck
  }
  isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="email">Email
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="phone">Phone
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="sms">SMS
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="whatsapp">Whatsapp
<input type="checkbox" onclick="togglecheckboxes()" value="Toggle all">Toggle All
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll